# my data is not showing in 'network' of developer tools and I'm getting a 404 error instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ajax, express

Hey so I'm following a react and node js tutorial on youtube
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRCDsB9i3bI][1]
[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRCDsB9i3bI

The tutorial is about creating an e-commerce website using react and node.

I've arrived at minute 1:51:21 but I didn't get the same result.
I'm supposed to receive the data in an xhr/ajax request in network (Developer Tools) but I'm receiving this error in console instead:

> DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for
> chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/iframe_handler.map:
> HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

> DevTools
> failed to load source map: Could not load content for
> chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/content.map:
> HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Note :The 'Server is ready' shows up on screen in localhost:5000 and if I go to localhost:5000/api/products the data 'products' shows up on the screen.

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import data from './data.js';

const app = express();

app.get('/api/products', (req, res)=>{
    res.send(data.products);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.send('Server is ready');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Serve at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

data.js

```
const data = {
    products:[
        {
            _id: '1',
            name: 'Nike Java Shirt',
            category: 'Shirts',
            image: '/images/product-3.jpg',
            price:120,
            countInStock: 10,
            brand:'Nike',
            rating: 4.5,
            numReviews:10,
            description: 'high quality product',
        },
        {
            _id: '2',
            name: 'Supreme Java Shirt',
            category: 'Shirts',
            image: '/images/product-4.jpeg',
            price:400,
            countInStock: 20,
            brand:'Adidas',
            rating: 4.0,
            numReviews:10,
            description: 'high quality product',
        },
        {
            _id: '3',
            name: 'Lacoste Evolution Shirt',
            category: 'Shirts',
            image: '/images/product-5.jpeg',
            price:220,
            countInStock: 0,
            brand:'Lacoste',
            rating: 4.8,
            numReviews:17,
            description: 'high quality product',
        },
        {
            _id: '4',
            name: 'Pants',
            category: 'Pants',
            image: '/images/product-6.jpg',
            price:78,
            countInStock: 15,
            brand:'Nike',
            rating: 1.5,
            numReviews:15,
            description: 'high quality product',
        },
        {
            _id: '5',
            name: 'Puma Pants',
            category: 'Pants',
            image: '/images/product-7.jpeg',
            price:65,
            countInStock: 5,
            brand:'Puma',
            rating: 2.5,
            numReviews:10,
            description: 'high quality product',
        },
        {
            _id: '6',
            name: 'Adidas Fit Pants',
            category: 'Pants',
            image: '/images/product-8.jpg',
            price:139,
            countInStock: 12,
            brand:'Adidas',
            rating: 4,
            numReviews:15,
            description: 'high quality product',
        },
    ]
};

export default data;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "brand",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --watch backend --exec node --experimental-modules backend/server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.13"
  }
}
```

folder :

```
Brand
  -> backend
    -> data.js
    -> server.js
  -> frontend
  package-lock.json
  package.json
```

Thank you in advance <3 I appreciate any help and sorry if my question is stupid or obvious :p I'm still a noob in all this.

PS: I tried researching the errors and I only found ways to hide the errors not solve them (I'm not sure if I researched the wrong keywords)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the proxy in package.json from:

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000"
```

to:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```